# Wygwam - Applying style to Unordered List

Tags: ee2, pixelandtonic, wygwam

How can I apply a style in Wygwam editor so that the following code

```
<ul>
    <li>Here's bullet point number one</li>
</ul>
```

Changes to this

```
<ul data-bullet="ti-arrow-right" class="lead">
    <li><i class="ti-arrow-right"></i>Here's bullet point number one</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can without a parsing the data after it is submitted. Addone would be needed.

My only thoughts would be to use the style drop down. So for example they paste the list in, then highlight it, and in the WYGWAM styles drop down they select a style which allpies what you want:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles